# Multiple drag and drop elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I found this code, thats lets you drag and drop an item in an specific area, but I failed to rewrite it, so that it allowes multiple elments to drag and drop, because i dont know how to get the id of the dragged object from the drop_handler function.

```js
let offsetX;
let offsetY;

onDragStart = function(ev) {
  const rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.x;
  offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.y;
};

drop_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const left = parseInt(id2.style.left);
  const top = parseInt(id2.style.top);

  id1.style.position = 'absolute';
  id1.style.left = ev.clientX - left - offsetX + 'px';
  id1.style.top = ev.clientY - top - offsetY + 'px';
  id2.appendChild(document.getElementById("id1"));
};

dragover_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
};
```

```html
<div id="id1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div</div>


<div id="id2" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:50px;border:2px solid red; cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Div
</div>
```

Comment: I see the problem! You can not have `...getElementById("id1") in *drop_handler* if you have more than one draggable box because *id1* is hard coded. You need a variable which has the id of the box which was dragged... Not sure how to do that (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I have made a div just to keep track of the id of the draggable box. A *data* attribute is assigned the id from *dragover_handler* and then it can be read from *drop_handler*:

The other answer has a more sensible way of saving the id than this. There is no need to put it into an HTML element. If you are going to put the value into an HTML element it would be more sensible to use an appropriate existing element such as the target box than to create an unrelated element for the purpose.

```js
let offsetX;
let offsetY;

const keepTrackOfID = document.querySelector('#keep-track-of-id');

onDragStart = function(ev) {
  const rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.x;
  offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.y;
  
  keepTrackOfID.setAttribute('data-dragged-id', ev.target.id);
  
};

drop_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const left = parseInt(id2.style.left);
  const top = parseInt(id2.style.top);

  id1.style.position = 'absolute';
  id1.style.left = ev.clientX - left - offsetX + 'px';
  id1.style.top = ev.clientY - top - offsetY + 'px';
  id2.appendChild(document.getElementById(keepTrackOfID.dataset.draggedId));
  
  console.log(ev.target.id);
  
};

dragover_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
};
```

```html
<div id="id1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div 1</div>

<div id="id1b" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div 1b</div>

<div id='keep-track-of-id'></div>

<div id="id2" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:50px;border:2px solid red; cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Div
</div>
```

Comment: Why an extra div? You could add the `data-dragged-id` to the `dropContainer` since that will always be there?

Comment: @0stone0 I agree (also mentioned it now in my answer) there is no need for extra div. The `dropContainer` would have made a better choice. As far as I understand you have just declared a variable in the global (relative to the two functions) space to keep track of the *id*. That seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the `onDragStart`, 'save' the `dragElement`. This way you can use this variable in `drop_handler` to move the item.

I've added a `const` for the `dropElement` since this won't change.

```js
let offsetX;
let offsetY;
let dragElement = null;
const dropElement = document.getElementById("id-drop");

onDragStart = function(ev) {
  const rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.x;
  offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.y;
  
  dragElement = ev.target;
};

drop_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const left = parseInt(dropElement.style.left);
  const top = parseInt(dropElement.style.top);

  dragElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  dragElement.style.left = ev.clientX - left - offsetX + 'px';
  dragElement.style.top = ev.clientY - top - offsetY + 'px';
  dropElement.appendChild(dragElement);
};

dragover_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
};
```

```html
<div id="id1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div #1</div>

<div id="id2" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div #2</div>

<div id="id-drop" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:50px;border:2px solid red; cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Div
</div>
```